# Excess pressure variation inside the air bubble when bubble is not considered to be small

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

We know the pressure inside is greater than outside but that is for a point just inside the bubble not very inside to it to be 2T/R and in many cases inside pressure variation is considered negligible because of bubble to be of small size but if that is not negligible how the pressure variation inside varies as one goes from centre of bubble to a point R/2 etc.. ? And why we neglect the pressure variation inside the bubble in case of small? There might be difference in height  isnt due to mass if air?

Comment: Why do you state that there is a pressure difference within the bubble? I would suppose that pressure is homogeneous within the bubble.

Comment: I dont know thats what i want to know if thats the case by physics intuition.

Comment: Yes, I do not see any reason why the pressure should not be homogenous inside the bubble. Differences might arise from differences in temperature (or variation of it), but the system will equilibrate itself.

Comment: Inside air bubble there is mass of air so due to it height difference pressure might be there isnt ?

Comment: Oh, you mean a really big bubble.....Then it will probably cause deformation of the bubble - if its surface can sustain those. If you get a 10 km bubble then there is also to consider that pressure outside the bubble is different around its surface. So yes, the pressure inside the bubble will be different, but just because it has to compensate for the pressure outside.
On a side note: surface tension will probably never be able to sustain those stresses and the bubble will collapse.

Comment: Hmm may you show by an answer how it varies ?